# Nlog not loggin to File

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nlog

my nlog not creating files. I Use the same configuration in another project and everythink is Ok, but in new project nlog not create new files.

Nlog config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="utf-8" ?>

autoReload= "true"
  internalLogLevel =" Trace"
  internalLogFile ="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

<targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"
        fileName="C:\beka\logs\logfile.txt"
        
        />

    <target name="exceptions" xsi:type="File"
        layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}"
        fileName="C:\beka\logs\logfileExceptions.txt"
        
        />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="exceptions" />
</rules>
```

On the console I can see that the log has been called but its not sent to a file.

I think the problem can be in c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt becouse this file has references to another project. And when i start another project internal-nlog.txt is update but when i start this project internal-nlog-txt doesnt update

Nlog action = content,
Copy to outputDirectory = copy if newer

Comment: I will add that when I run a second project, the file internal-nlog.txt is updated, but when i start this projekt internal-nlog.txt does not update

Comment: maybe you need to run project as administrator cause the file in c drive

Comment: unfortunately that's not it

Comment: do you run both project together as same time ?

Comment: No, i run only one project

Comment: lets try this clear text in log file and then try again . if its not worked then just create another file and see if the file fill with the logs ?

Comment: I cleared text in log file and i tried in a diffrent but all time but it not work. In another project i have the save config and everythink work good but here when i start project it doesnt update files :/

Comment: You are aware, this is not valid (nor well-formed) XML, right? The `autoReload`et al are just dangling there in no-mans-land.

Comment: Could please try with `fileName="${basedir}/log.txt" />` you could have a look here in [this link](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2938)

Comment: Could there be another nlog config file that is loaded instead of this one? Check the info about [File locations](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-locations)